# Parsing Timex Expressions in .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, botframework, azure-language-understanding

Using LUIS engine, I receive `XXXX-10-28` as a date in the Entity Value.

I've tried using `Chronic` to parse but Chronic does not work with `timex` library/formats.

I'm expecting following strings as inputs

- `XXXX-10-28` should equate to `2018-10-28` (future)
- `2018-10-02TMO` should equate to `2018-10-02` i.e. `tomorrow`

Please note that `XXXX-XX` represents `YYYY-MM` but it doesn't have `numeric` values

Is there any library, or way to parse such strings to a valid `datetime` format in `ASP.NET Core`?

Comment: Timex is a libray, not a format. What you posted looks like `YYYY-MM-DD`, the ISO8601 date format which can be parsed out-of-the-box by `DateTime.Parse`. For example `DateTime.Parse("2018-11-13")` will return a DateTime object whose value is November 11, 2018

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Timex is actually a format. It's used by the [Datetimev2 prebuilt entity for LUIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-reference-prebuilt-datetimev2).  [Find the spec here.](http://www.timeml.org/tempeval2/tempeval2-trial/guidelines/timex3guidelines-072009.pdf)

Comment: Note that `2018-10-02TMO` does not mean tomorrow, but 'in the morning of 2018-10-02'.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Microsoft.Recognizers.Text.DataTypes.TimexExpression package [from NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Recognizers.Text.DataTypes.TimexExpression/). It's part of the Microsoft Recognizers Text project [here on github](https://github.com/microsoft/Recognizers-Text)

I found two ways you can use this library:

#### Parse the expression using a TimexProperty and guess the year yourself:

```
var parsed = new Microsoft.Recognizers.Text.DataTypes.TimexExpression.TimexProperty("XXXX-10-28");
Console.WriteLine(parsed.Year); // = null
Console.WriteLine(parsed.Month); // = 28
Console.WriteLine(parsed.DayOfMonth); // = 10
```

#### Resolve times useing the TimexResolver

```
var resolution = Microsoft.Recognizers.Text.DataTypes.TimexExpression.TimexResolver.Resolve(new [] { "XXXX-10-28" }, System.DateTime.Today)
```

The `resolution.Values` will contain an array with two resolution entries, one for the previous occurrence of that date and one for the next occurrence of that date (based on the DateTime you pass into the Resolve method.

Note that from personal experience and from what I saw on github, that at the time of writing, this package can be quite [buggy](https://github.com/microsoft/Recognizers-Text/issues/1560) with the more advanced expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Use a custom format pattern:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
class MainClass {
  public static void Main (string[] args) {
    var format = "1234-10-30";
    var date = DateTime.ParseExact(format, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    Console.WriteLine (date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
  }
}
```

[Example](https://repl.it/@BanksySan/LightblueCostlyTelephones)

Comment: There's no reason to use `ParseExact` with `YYYY-MM-DD`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos There would be if only this format was correct though, which the OP is implying by his examples.

Comment: My initial comment would be that the OP only asked how to parse the strig. If there's any chance of mixing up formats though (because multiple libraries were involved?), the code should validate the input indeed

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`DateTime.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparse?view=netframework-4.7.2) or [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact?view=netframework-4.7.2) along with a [custom date/time format string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) in order to accomplish this.

Based on your example, I think the format string you'd want is `yyyy-MM-dd`, although you may need to tweak this slightly.

Example:

```
var input = "2018-10-28";
var format = "yyyy-MM-dd";
DateTime parsed;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(input, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out parsed))
{
    // Do whatever you want with "parsed"
}
```

Comment: `YYYY-MM-DD` can be parsed by `DateTime.Parse()` directly